# Send EWMH messages with Qt on X11

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, x11, xlib

How would I send an [extended window manager hint](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.4.html#idm45703947050608) using Qt5/6 on X11? I've found an example [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/1493-setting-EWM-(extended-window-manager)-hints-via-Qt4-(X11)) but I'm not exactly sure what to do with it.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <Q11Info>
 
// In widget constructor
 
// Allocate a hint structure - don't forget to XFree() in destructor!
XWMHints* hints(XAllocWMHints());
 
// Populate the hints structure with the hints you want to activate here.
// hints->flags = ...etc.
 
// Set the hints on the X11 window for the widget.
XSetWMHints(QX11Info::display(), static_cast<Window>(this->winId()), hints);
```

I'm not sure what the example means by "populate the hints structure".

Comment: Qt is meant to be cross-plaform, so why would you do this in a Qt application?

Comment: @LászlóPapp Because I'm making a panel (taskbar) for Linux and this is the only way to keep windows from going over it.

Comment: You do not need Qt then...

Comment: @LászlóPapp I don't even know how to do this in regular XLib though. I thought Qt would make it easier, but now that I think about it that doesn't really make any sense...

Comment: Qt will make it easier to do platform specific things. It will make it easier to do cross-platform things.